# Surround video tag with SVG

Tags: css, html, svg, html5-video

I'm trying to create a 'component' with a SVG monitor and a `video` tag placed exactly inside the svg. I've been able to coerce the video to sit *exactly* where I want it to with the help of `position: absolute`, `top` and `left` settings. Unfortunately, all of this fails if I change the size of the svg element. Here's an [example](https://codepen.io/gurupras/pen/pVdaeV) of what I have so far.

What is the right way to give a video element some SVG outline such that the combination always scales correctly.

Comment: would using px's instead of % help in the .embed-video class

Comment: I don't think that would work at all. I always thought that when you use `px`, you're sort of hard-coding stuff to work at a specific resolution.